# ServiceStack GET Request Expects Body Data

Tags: json, request, get, servicestack

I'm using the ServiceStack v6 framework for an API service with the OAuth as the authenticator provider.

The authentication process works fine but after that when I'm requesting some data from the API through the GET request process then in order to get the expected results, I need to set in the "body" an empty JSON value (something like: {}). In different case, I'm getting an HTML output produced by the framework which is not what I need.

On the below screen, the needed results are coming on Postman with an empty JSON value on the body part
[image: 1st result]

On the below screen, unexpected results are coming on Postman with no value on the body part.
[image: 2nd result]

How can I get the expected result without any value on the body part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include your Request & Response DTO definitions to help identify what your API is expected to accept and return.

If you want the server to return a JSON response you need to instruct it to by adding `Accept: application/json` to your HTTP Request.

Otherwise a JSON response is implied if you call the API via the [JSON /api Route](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#json-api-pre-defined-route), e.g. if your Request DTO is `GetLoginUser` you can call the API via `/api/GetLoginUser`.